# KeyError: Python script executed by linux service unable to access environment var

Tags: python, linux, service, raspberry-pi

So I have a simple service on my Raspberry Pi that runs a Python script on boot. I have also set the env variable by running `export OPSESPORT=XXXX`. This is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My desc
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/path/to/file/somefile.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And in somefile.py, I have:

```
import os
PORT = int(os.environ['OPSESPORT'])
#other code
```

Which leads to the following error when checking logs of the service:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File  line 141, in <module>
     main()
   File  line 83, in main
     PORT = int(os.environ['OPSESPORT'])
   File  in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'OPSESPORT'
```

This is super weird since if I just run the script, `python somefile.py`, then it works fine, but if I start the service with `sudo systemctl start name.service` which then runs the script, it can't access the key. For reference, I am using Python 2.7.13 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

Comment: When you execute the service through systemd another shell it doesn't inherit yours shell environment. I would suggest you to use paraments instead of environment variables. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use sudo it doesn't use the same env variables. Can you run systemctl start name.service without super user privileges ?

Edit: Try adding 
`[Service]
Enviroment="OPSESPORT=XXX"`

Comment: Running without sudo didnt work but your adding Environment to service worked. This seems to be a problem if you want to push the service file to github but something private is stored in the env key.

Comment: From the sudo manual:  `-E, --preserve-env`. Try running your original script with this flag.

Comment: Which command do I add it to? I tried `sudo -E systemctl start name.service`. Also tried adding -E in ExecStart within the service file. Neither worked.